# Trying to access device in different subnet via linux hostapd access point

Tags: linux, dhcp, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

First I apologize if my knowledge of networks is humorously lacking. I appreciate any and all feedback!

I turned my raspberry pi into a private wireless access point using hostapd on my wlan0 interface. Now I would like to connect a Philips Hue to the pi via eth0 (wifi is not an option). From what I have been reading, it is easiest to have different interfaces on different subnets so my wlan0 is on 192.168.0.X while my eth0 is on 192.168.1.X.

To connect a bulb, I need to access the Hue at its assigned IP address (which is 192.168.1.19). However, my laptop which is connected to the 192.168.0.X subnet cannot access it. I have tried changing my subnet masks to 255.255.0.0 but to no avail. I have mostly been looking at subnet masks and bridging as possible paths.

**Any ideas on how I can access the Hue's IP from a different subnet?**

*/etc/network/interfaces:*

```
auto lo
    iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.1.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 192.168.0.0
```

*/etc/dnsmasq.conf:*

```
interface=wlan0
    dhcp-range=192.168.0.2,192.168.0.20,255.255.255.0,24h
interface=eth0
    dhcp-range=192.168.1.2,192.168.1.20,255.255.255.0,24h
```

*Also in /etc/dhcpcd.conf I have included the line*

```
denyinterfaces wlan0
```